# How do you style comments after they are pulled out of a database?

Tags: php, html, css

On my website you can post a comment, but I am unsure how to style them using CSS. I remember reading something about using ul and li tags but I can't figure it out. I want each individual comment to have a border, background color, etc. Here is the PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM catharsis";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();
echo "<h4><center>Let it out.</center></h4>";

$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $name = mysql_result($result,$num - $i,"message");
    echo "$name<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to code this so that I can give a class to the `echo "$name<br>";` and therefore style my comments with CSS.

Comment: I changed the formatting of your code so it's easier to read quickly (which tends to get you better answers) and removed the `comments` tag (because your question is related to any styling of a `<ul>` and `comments` seems to imply code-commenting.

Answer (score 4):

Do:

```
echo '<ul class="comments">';

for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    $name = mysql_result($result,$num - $i,"message");
    echo "<li>$name</li>";
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Then you can style it with this CSS:

```
ul.comments li {
 // style goes here
}
```

You'll probably want to re-style `ul.comments` too, since I doubt you want the default.

Alternately, you could do just `<ul>` and make each `<li>` into `<li class="comment">`

Answer (score 1):

you would need to style both the `<UL>` and `<LI>` elements in CSS.  When you echo them out, you would start with an unordered (bullet) list `<UL>` and each new comment would be 
`<LI>My nifty comment</LI>`.  You can style the UL so that it has no bullets using

```
list-style-type: none;
```